# ROS packages not only for Ubuntu - OBS Build Service

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it planned by the ROS community to provide packages for mainstream Linux distributions, like Fedora and OpenSuSe?

To me it's completely understandable, that Ubuntu is a recommded choice. However, I find setting ROS up on a non-Ubuntu system is really hard (I didn't succeed on Fedora 18, neither on OpenSuSe 12.3). In fact, I ended up creating a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation only for ROS Fuerte, which is quite redundant in my case.

As I see, in the last two years more and more people left the Ubuntu community - for numerous reasons we all know (Unity, Mir, outdated packages, privacy issues etc.).

Fedora has opened a [feature plan](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ROS_Fuerte) for ROS, which is at 0% completion. For OpenSuSe, there are packaging efforts made by [Spencer Jackson](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=home%3Aspencerjackson%3AROS).

What about the [OpenSuSe Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65089/ros-packages-not-only-for-ubuntu---obs-build-service/) by [Peter Roos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2915/peter-roos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We would like to have ROS packaged for RPM based systems.  We have designed bloom to be extendable to generate spec files instead of control files.  If you want to follow this up I suggest starting a discussion on the [ros-sig-buildsystem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-buildsystem)

THe OBS looks like a good way to get the packages built once they are released and if we could setup a pipeline to feed them in that would be great.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2